# Why I can't get phoneNumber?

Tags: node.js, backend, nest

I want to log in with phone number, but I don get pnone number on nestjs.

When I send this:
[image]
Everythink is okay.

But if i send this:
[image]
I can't log in.

So I added  in constructor  usernameField: 'email', phoneField: 'phoneNumber', for cheking but It's not working.
In webstorm I wrote console.log( `pass ${password}`) I see:

[image]

LocalStrategy:

```js
    @Injectable()
    
    export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    
      constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
        super({
          usernameField: 'email',
          phoneField: 'phoneNumber',
        });
      }
    
      async validate(
        email: string,
        password: string,
        phoneNumber: string,
      ): Promise<any> {
    
        console.log(` mail ${email}`)
        console.log(` pass ${password}`)
        console.log(` phone ${phoneNumber}`)
    
        const user = await this.authService.validateUser(
          email,
          password,
          phoneNumber,
        );
        // console.log(user)
    
        if (!user) {
          throw new UnauthorizedException('Неверный логин или пароль');
        }
    
        return user;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done it.

```java
    @Injectable()
    export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    
    constructor(
      private authService: AuthService,
      private moduleRef: ModuleRef
    ) {
    super({
      passReqToCallback: true,
      usernameField: 'email',
      phoneNumber: 'phoneNumber',
      passwordField: 'password',
    });
  }
    
async validate(
    request: Request,
    email: string,
    phoneNumber: string,
    password: string,
    ): Promise<any> {
    
    const contextId = ContextIdFactory.getByRequest(request);
    const flex = await this.moduleRef.resolve(AuthService, contextId);
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(
      request.body,
      email,
      phoneNumber,
      password,
      );
    
      if (!user) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException('Неверный логин или пароль');
      }
        return user;
    }
}
```